# Facebook v2.3 API - Rerequesting Login Permissions

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-permissions

I am using the latest [LoginButton for Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3) and setting read permissions on like so:

```
mLoginFacebookButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday"));
```

The [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/permissions) is kind of hazy on this:

> Your app should handle the case where someone had declined to grant your app one of the permissions you requested. If your app must have one of the declined permissions to work, you can request them again by using the LoginManager as in the examples above.

So when I ask for a users birthday (which is essential to the functionality of the app) on login and they decline, I throw up a dialog explaining why I need it. Then what exactly should I do? I am currently calling this when they dismiss the dialog:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginFragment.this, 
Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday"));
```

Which asks for the birthday again, so that's fine. But [this doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3) seems to indicate that behaviour will be flagged:

> If someone has declined a permission for your app, the login dialog won't let your app re-request the permission unless you pass `auth_type=rerequest` along with your request.
>
> You may receive Developer Alerts if your app repeatedly directs users to permissions dialogs after they deny permissions. To stop receiving these alerts, follow these guidelines.

Is my call to LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions() passing `auth_type=rerequest` behind the scenes? Will I receive developer alerts for this kind of behaviour?

Comment: You should never pop the dialog directly. You should explain why you need birthday and give them a button they can click if they want to give it to you

Comment: Yeah that's basically what I'm doing, and if they click okay to dismiss my friendly dialog, it just calls `logInWithReadPermissions` again and brings the user back to the fb login which seems wrong. The only alternative I can think of is to try and override the default Login Button behaviour to behave differently if it's clicked again after a permission has been denied - but that seems very hacky too

Comment: Your code is fine. Calling LoginManager's logInWithReadPermissions will add the rerequest flag for you if you already have a valid access token.

Comment: @MingLi, how to set the existing token to the ```LoginManager```. 

Also, is there a way to set ```auth_type``` explicit?